# Google Maps AutocompleteResultsViewController crash in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working on an app and have integrated GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces SDK into it. When I open it on iOS 10 based device, clicking on Search Bar crashes the app. I have also added GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController. I am attaching the code

```
    var mapView: GMSMapView?

    var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
    var searchController: UISearchController?        

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView = GMSMapView()
        mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)
        mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)

        mapView.delegate = self

        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

        searchController!.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)

        let subView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 45.0))

        subView.addSubview((searchController?.searchBar)!)
        self.view.addSubview(subView)

        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
        func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController, didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace) {
            searchController?.active = false

            mapView.animateToLocation(place.coordinate)
        }

        func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: NSError){
            print("Error: ", error.description)
        }

        func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        }

        func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }
    }

    extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
        func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            searchController?.active = false
        }

        func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            let doneBtn = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
            doneBtn?.enabled = false
        }

        func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            let doneBtn = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
            doneBtn?.enabled = true
        }
}
```

Whenever I tap on searchBar, the app crashes on typing any character. I don't see any result and can't even type a single word. Error that I am getting is

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x43622b, 0x1ca0f050 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
* thread #1: tid = 0x4382b9, 0x1ca0f050 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
* frame #0: 0x1ca0f050 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x1d7a9d4c CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:] + 108
frame #2: 0x00933772 AppName`+[GMSPlacesClient sharedClient] + 122
frame #3: 0x0092f702 AppName`-[GMSAutocompleteFetcher requestAutocompleteResultsWithText:] + 202
frame #4: 0x0092f55a AppName`-[GMSAutocompleteFetcher sendOrDelayRequest:] + 82
frame #5: 0x0092f4fa AppName`-[GMSAutocompleteFetcher sourceTextHasChanged:] + 82
frame #6: 0x0093ad6a AppName`-[GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource sourceTextHasChanged:] + 234
frame #7: 0x00943d7e AppName`-[GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController updateSearchResultsForSearchController:] + 202
frame #8: 0x2321d736 UIKit`-[UISearchController _searchBar:textDidChange:] + 84
frame #9: 0x229e202a UIKit`-[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _searchFieldEditingChanged] + 268
frame #10: 0x22823b5c UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 76
frame #11: 0x22823aea UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 62
frame #12: 0x2280dc86 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 470
frame #13: 0x229e1da8 UIKit`-[UITextField fieldEditorDidChange:] + 218
frame #14: 0x2282dd02 UIKit`-[UITextInputController _sendDelegateChangeNotificationsForText:selection:] + 122
frame #15: 0x229b2c7a UIKit`-[UITextInputController _insertText:fromKeyboard:] + 822
frame #16: 0x229b2008 UIKit`-[UITextInputController insertText:] + 406
frame #17: 0x22b3d142 UIKit`-[UIFieldEditor insertFilteredText:] + 540
frame #18: 0x231da3f0 UIKit`-[UITextField insertFilteredText:] + 96
frame #19: 0x229b1d98 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl insertText:] + 136
frame #20: 0x22bf6e94 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl performKeyboardOutput:] + 524
frame #21: 0x22bf6ab6 UIKit`__55-[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyboardInput:executionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 334
frame #22: 0x2281831a UIKit`-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 400
frame #23: 0x1e0cb3da Foundation`__NSThreadPerformPerform + 386
frame #24: 0x1d765c8a CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
frame #25: 0x1d765794 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 438
frame #26: 0x1d763a6a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 762
frame #27: 0x1d6b3072 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 486
frame #28: 0x1d6b2e80 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
frame #29: 0x1ee5bbfc GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 156
frame #30: 0x22859cce UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 574
frame #31: 0x22854400 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 150
frame #32: 0x00232110 AppName`main + 172 at AppDelegate.swift:28
frame #33: 0x1ce7e50a libdyld.dylib`start + 2
```

The project is on Xcode 8 with Swift 2.3.

I don't know why I am getting this error and not able to resolve it. Please look into it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should not you distinguish between iPad and non-ipad cases? None iPad would not have a popover presentation and for iPad's case you'll have to set a bar item or source view for the popover presenter? Like: .popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = barItem;

Comment: It could be related to usability issue as discussed in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/9QR06XoF350) wherein it was stated that it was already fixed in release of iOS 10. You may also try updating your iOS and see if this is functional. If it still doesn't work, you may [send feedback to the Google Maps team](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en&oco=1) regarding the issues you are having on iOS 10.

Comment: Hey did u got a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following:

Old:

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GooglePlaces.h>
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:GoogleAPIKey]
```

Updated working code:

```
@import GooglePlaces;
[GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:GoogleAPIKey];
```

Latest SDK is pointing to GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h, instead of GoogleMaps/GooglePlaces.h
Check this link:
https://developers.google.com/places/migrate-to-v2

Answer (score 0):

`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2`

Some exception breakpoints seem to be triggered probably from parts of the GoogleMaps or GooglePlaces SDKs, as evident when you click the search bar.

Disable exception breakpoints for all exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Danoram. But I added this exception breakpoint to pin point where the problem is.